# Textblob is over-generalizing text and classifying it as neutral

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I'm using textblob to determine the sentiment of twitter text but some results have no polarity and no subjectivity (making them neutral sentiment -
[tweets cleaned and placed in pd.dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VKgL.png))

[This is a chart of the overall contrasts between sentiment (showing way more neutral)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KCd5.png)

My code is below

```
# Create a function to get the subjectivity
def getSubjectivity(text):
   return TextBlob(text).sentiment.subjectivity

# Create a function to get the polarity
def getPolarity(text):
   return  TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity


# Create two new columns 'Subjectivity' & 'Polarity'
df['Subjectivity'] = df['Tweets'].apply(getSubjectivity)
df['Polarity'] = df['Tweets'].apply(getPolarity)

# Show the new dataframe with columns 'Subjectivity' & 'Polarity'
df

# Subjectivity < 1  but > 0 is more factual, > 1 is very opinionated (0 and +1 are min/max)
# Polarity < 0 is more negative, > 0 is more positive (-1 and +1 are the min/max)
```

Comment: Sentiment analysis classifying code - `# Create a function to compute negative (-1), neutral (0) and positive (+1) analysis
def getAnalysis(score):

  if score < 0:
    return 'Negative'
  elif score == 0:
    return 'Neutral'
  else:
    return 'Positive'
df['Analysis'] = df['Polarity'].apply(getAnalysis)
# Show the dataframe
`

Comment: Please do **not** post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your question instead.